# textFieldShouldReturn: method issue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have to dismiss keyboard control when i'm done typing in a textfield, so i'm using  `textFieldShouldReturn`: method inside of which i use `[textField resignFirstResponder]`. Up till here its fine.

What i find weird is that if i return `YES` or `NO` to this method, the behavior remains the same. I checked the documentation and it said you should return YES only to implement default behavior,otherwise return `NO`. Which default implementation are they mentioning in the docs?? I didn't get that.

Answer (score 0):

This method is called just when you type return key. If you return NO this will be ignored. If you want to dismiss keyboard return YES.
You can also call `[textField resignFirstResponder]` in 
textFieldDidEndEditing: if you want to dismiss keyboard when you finished editing textField.

Comment: When i return NO the behavior is the same as incase of returning YES.

Answer (score 0):

The [Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldReturn%3a) clearly states that :

> Be aware that this method provides only a recommendation about whether
>   editing should end. Even if you return NO from this method, it is
>   possible that editing might still end. For example, this might happen
>   when the text field is forced to resign the first responder status by
>   being removed from its parent view or window.
>
> Implementation of this method by the delegate is optional. If it is
>   not present, the first responder status is resigned as if this method
>   had returned YES.

The situation, when you don't  want to use the `default behaviour` then use the `return NO`.

**For Example :**

> FOr some constraint you don't want to dismiss the keyboard Or other
>   textFields as the becomeFirstResponder even when you tap on other
>   textFields.

If you need to understand practically try this:

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

    if ([textField.text length]< 4) {
        return NO;
       // [self animateUItextField:self.txtNewPassword];

    }else{
        return YES;

}
}
```

Here Clarifying your issue :

```
You are about to resign the textField manually, So there is nothing to deal with the return expression,
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I still didn't get it. I tried your code but i couldn't get it.

Comment: TRy to understand the condition. and then according to that try to invoke return key